# How to change the cursors dynamically in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to change the cursor in runtime dynamically.

```
PROCEDURE test_cur(a IN VARCHAR2,
                   b IN VARCHAR2)
IS 
CURSOR cur_a IS
SELECT x.col_a,x.col_b FROM tab_a x, tab_b y
WHERE x.col_a = y.col_a

BEGIN
IF (condition) THEN
 FOR rec IN cur_a LOOP
   --DO SOME WORK
 END LOOP;
ELSE
 FOR rec IN cur_a LOOP
```

In this else section i want to add some other code in to the where clause of the cursor. I wanted to know is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> In this else section i want to add some other code in to the where clause of the cursor.

Then simply use a **Cursor FOR loop** thus you could use your desired query to loop.

For example,

```
IF (condition) THEN
 FOR rec IN (SELECT .. FROM table_1 ..) 
    LOOP -- 
      --DO SOME WORK
    END LOOP;
ELSE
 FOR rec IN (SELECT .. FROM table_2 ..) 
    LOOP
       --DO SOME OTHER WORK
    END LOOP;
```

Of course, another way is to use **dynamic sql**. Declare a **varchar2** variable and assign the static part of the sql.

Inside each **IF-ELSE** part keep **concatenating** the required dynamic sql.

For example,

```
DECLARE
   v_sql VARCHAR2(2000);
   TYPE cur IS REF CURSOR;
   v_cur cur;
BEGIN
   v_sql := 'SELECT x.col_a,x.col_b FROM tab_a x, tab_b y WHERE x.col_a = y.col_a';

IF (condition) 
THEN
   v_sql := v_sql || ' AND <desired conditions>';
   OPEN v_cur FOR v_sql;
   LOOP
   --DO SOME WORK
   END LOOP;
ELSE
   v_sql := v_sql || ' AND <other desired conditions>';
   OPEN v_cur FOR v_sql;
   LOOP
   --DO SOME WORK
   END LOOP;
```

Comment: Lalith, My cursor is about 350 lines, so your answer will reduce the readability of the code.

Answer (score 2):

why not create one cursor and put a part of the clause with your condition:

```
CURSOR cur_a IS
SELECT x.col_a,x.col_b FROM tab_a x, tab_b y
WHERE x.col_a = y.col_a
  AND (condition AND (rest of your where clause));
```

So only one cursor and as many 'conditions' you need.
Know that Oracle will optimize the where clause to ignore all the parts where the condition if false (so no costs other than the compilation).

I used this technique in very complex search screens with Oracle. Works very well.

I hope that helps.

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Dynamic SQL for this if in case your where condition changes dynamically.
Declare the select queries you wanted along with various where conditions. Based on the conditions execute the corresponding sql

Refer the official documentation at below link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm